# Weka: how to calculate and draw histogram in java code

Tags: java, swing, weka

I'm totally new to Weka.
I'm trying to use Weka from my Java code. I need to build a histogram, like you see in the right-bottom corner in the Weka Explorer at the screenshot. How can I do that? What classes are responsible for this histogram?

I've found some Discretizing classes in Weka Sources, which seem to be able to split data into beans.

```
weka.filters.supervised.attribute.Discretize
weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Discretize
```

I'm not sure, how to use this classes, but even if I do, how do I draw a histogram using `JPanel` and `JFrame` from `javax.swing`?

I just want to draw a histogram of one feature of IRIS dataset.

[image: Weka iris dataset loaded in gui]

Thanks!